# How delete Inactive destinations in ActiveMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket

i need configure activemq to delete inactive queues  :

Configuration using websocket as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

      @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {


          config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .setUserDestinationPrefix("/user")
            .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue","/user")
            .setRelayHost("localhost")
            .setRelayPort(61613);


        }


        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS();
        }


}
```

How can add the below destinationPolicy in the spring boot ? How import this part ?

```
  <destinationPolicy>
     <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
           <policyEntry queue=">" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000"/>
        </policyEntries>
     </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>

</broker>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this bean definion to your configuration

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setSchedulePeriodForDestinationPurge(10000);
    broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");
    PolicyMap policyMap = new PolicyMap();
    PolicyEntry policyEntry = new PolicyEntry();
    policyEntry.setGcInactiveDestinations(true);
    policyEntry.setInactiveTimeoutBeforeGC(30000);
    policyEntry.setQueue(">");
    List<PolicyEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PolicyEntry>();
    entries.add(policyEntry);
    policyMap.setPolicyEntries(entries);
    broker.setDestinationPolicy(policyMap);
    return broker;
}
```

and verify that you have these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There are away to see available queues in active MQ ? administration view ?  as you know it's embedded MQ

Comment: JMX with visualvm ? by default it is activated